# Report Viewer & vb.net 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, reportviewer

In vs 2008 when opening a Report (rdlc) there was an option for Report Data Sources. I don't see this in vs 2010. How can I find it in 2010?

Answer (score 0):

**Using the Menu Item**

You should see it under View -> Report Data
(tends to only be present while a Report is the active window)

**Use the keyboard short cut**

While a Report is the active window press <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>

**Using the command window**

in the Command Window type  `>View.ReportData` again the active window must be a Rdlc or you'll get the error "Command "View.ReportData" is not available."

Comment: Yes, I see it now. But it does not let me select a DataSet that I can see in the data explorer. (Seems like this interface for the reports has changed drastically.)